# How to send verification code using plivo php api

Tags: plivo

I am using the Plivo API to send a message. I want to send a verification and check that code using the Plivo PHP API, [similar to this example.](http://shielded-hollows-9845.herokuapp.com/)

I have searched a lot but was unable to find sample code or an example in the Plivo PHP API.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/plivo/plivo-examples-php/blob/1540b743ab344de327a492339aa4c5215f4ce480/sms/send_sms.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code to that example: https://github.com/cachrisman/Plivo-2FA-App and here is an updated copy of that demo: https://plivo-2fa.herokuapp.com/.  It is written in python, but the concepts are the same and you should be able to translate it into PHP fairly easily.